# ActiveRecord ordering by relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
Loan.includes(:decisions).map{|l| l.decisions.last.try(:smart_rate)}
=> [2, nil, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, nil, nil, nil, nil, 1, nil, 1, nil, 1, nil, nil, nil, 3, nil, 3, 1, 1, nil, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, nil, 2, 1, nil, 1, nil, 1, 1, nil, 3, nil, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I'd like to sort Loans by their last decision's smart_rate. I'm not trying to sort the array, but the resulting Loan::ActiveRecord_Relation.

Can this be done via ActiveRecord?

Comment: What are you trying to do, can you explain a little more?

Comment: Updated a bit. This seems super easy, but for whatever reason I can't seem to get the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship on Decision then you could do this, the Loans should be in the correct order in the returned hash.

```
Decision.where(...).includes(:loan).order(:smart_rate).map(&:loan).uniq
```

Comment: I need the nils, though. I still need the the underlying loans, even if they don't have a decision. More importantly, I'm not trying to sort the resulting array, but the underlying collection.

Comment: we'd need a uniq as well there. this does everything in memory, as well. I'm trying to lean on the power of AR to handle this in the database.

Comment: Loan has_many :decisions. Your answer will result in several duplicate loans.